# How to send magento 2 Order emails through mailchimp?

Tags: order-email, magento2.3.0, mailchimp

I have **mail-chimp** account and successfully integrated with my Magento2 website.
I Want to send the order emails via **mail-chimp**.
Newsletter subscription is working fine and syncing.
Order is not syncing in the MailChimp, it's always empty as below.
[image]
But the order email is not sending via mail-chip. Can I send order email only through mail-chimp and other emails through Magento(ex - Customer registration success, Reset password, etc)

How can i send my transnational email via Mailchimp? Is there any possibility?

If i setup the mailchimp all Magento email going through mailchimp like **Forget password**, **Shipment notification**, **Credit memo** etc?

Comment: Have you follow this step https://mailchimp.com/help/create-order-notifications/

Comment: @ChiragPatel yes followed.

Comment: @Mujahidh how did you solve it?

Comment: How you send Transactional email through Mail-chimp?